# In xcode targets title is empty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I'm using XCODE 4.2.

In Xcode, title of targets is cleared like pic.

How can I restore targets title?

Is this no problem though targets title is empty?

[image]

Comment: create new project with some other name with more characters.Check is that showing target name or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the target title may not really be completely empty. Xcode4 doesn't seem to let you clear the title completely, but you can set it to a space.

Second, you can edit the target title. Just select the target so that the whole line is selected, and then click on the row. The title area should become editable, with any existing title selected. Type a new name, click somewhere else, and you're done.

Comment: When I enter the target title, I can't see cursor for editing. but, typing target title according your reply. So succeeded. ^^  Thank you~~

Comment: Thanks @hyekyung! This XCode bug had me stumped for a while. Still not sure how the target name gets blanked out in the first place though.